# I have a VB file of varying record length. I want to convert it in FB file

Tags: jcl, dfsort

I have a VB file of varying record length. I want to convert it in FB file. Input files are having record length of 4000, 4012, 4062 and so on..

I am using below SYSIN SORT card but not getting desired result.

```
//SYSIN DD *
     OPTION COPY
     OUTFIL FNAMES=SORTOUT,VTOF,OUTREC=(5,4000)
/*
```

How can I copy full input VB file to output FB file using JCL ?

Now what should I provide in OUTREC

Answer (score 1):

You just need to provide LRECL - 4 as the final length.  For example if the input LRECL=5000 and RECFM=VB then when you convert to RECFM=FB, you would provide the LRECL length as 5000 - 4 = 4996.

```
OPTION COPY 
OUTFIL FNAMES=SORTOUT,VTOF,OUTREC=(5,4996)
```

Since the RECFM=FB every record now will have a length of 4996. Short records are padded with spaces at the end.

Comment: My input is of varying length. It is VB file. It is not of fix record length.

Comment: You are converting a varying length to FIXED length , so the longest record will NOW be the length of every record. Since the RECFM=FB every record now will have a length equal to the longest record in your VB file. Short records are padded with spaces at the end.

Comment: My input file record length are varying from 3000 to 8000 length so if I provide the longest length 8000 in outrec then getting error -"END OF SORTOUT  FIELD BEYOND MAXIMUM RECORD LENGTH"

Comment: Did you read the instructions that are provided?  You just need to subtract 4 bytes from the LRECL of the VB file.  So if your VB file has LRECL=8000, then the longest record will ONLY be 8000 - 4 = 7996 bytes long.

Comment: I understood what you said but the problem is that everyday I am getting new VB file with different record length so I can not change the production jcl everyday so I need some jcl which can take input VB of any record length.

Comment: Asish,

If the file LRECL is changing every day then you need to generate dynamic control card

1. Get the DCB properties the file using LISTDS command
2. Read the output of LISTDS and generate the LRECL-4 symbol for DFSORT
3. Now use that symbol to copy the dataset with LRECL-4

Comment: I am able to get the first part in file READY                                            
  LISTDS 'file-name'  
file-name             
--RECFM-LRECL-BLKSIZE-DSORG                      
  VB    4164  27998   PS                         
--VOLUMES--                                      
  PRM101                                         
READY                                            
END                                              How to generate the LRECL symbol from this ?

Comment: If the input data is of varying length then maybe it's not such a good idea to convert to FB. Why does it have to be  FB?